# Is this a bug with iOS 8 simulator/device orientation

Tags: debugging, ios8, uiinterfaceorientation, xcode6.1, device-orientation

I'm using Xcode 6.1 The below code works with all iOS 7 simulators/devices. It works with iOS 8 = iPhone 4s, 5c, 5, 5s, iPad non-retina. However, the code doesn't rotate to UpsideDown orientation with iOS 8 for iPhone 6, 6+ and iPad Retina.

```
 -(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown);
}
```

Is this a bug? The above code is NOT deprecated according to researching it in Apple documents. How do I UNDO this bug to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it's the expected behaviour in iOS 8.3:
http://www.reddit.com/r/apple/comments/30xcn3/latest_ios_83_beta_removes_upside_down_home/